# How to create a mask in OpenCV.js?

Tags: javascript, opencv

I can create a mask in OPENCV C++ using cv::Mat::zeros and Rect.But i cannot find these features on OPENCV.js.How can i create a mask on OPENCV.js?

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(8, 8, CV_8U); // all 0
mask(Rect(2,2,4,4)) = 1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let src = cv.imread('canvasInput');
let dst = new cv.Mat();
// You can try more different parameters
let rect = new cv.Rect(100, 100, 200, 200);
dst = src.roi(rect);
cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dst);
src.delete();
dst.delete();
```

Taken from [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/de/d06/tutorial_js_basic_ops.html), specifically the Image ROI section